# TypeError: jasmine.getEnv().currentSpec is null

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, jasmine, typeerror

When I try to run my jasmine specs, I get

```
TypeError: jasmine.getEnv().currentSpec is null in 
    http://localhost:8888/__JASMINE_ROOT__/jasmine.js (line 498)
```

No idea why, not even sure where to begin looking.

Line 498 is:

```
return jasmine.getEnv().currentSpec.expect(actual);
```

I've been doing jasmine for several months now, but not on this project. I've never seen this happening before.

So, where do I start?

(This is jasmine gem in a rails 3.x project)

Comment: I had same issue, when i mistakenly wrote `describe` instead of `it` in my tests.

Comment: I don't think that was it, as I ran it on my local box and it seemed to work fine. I was running this on a tunnelled ssh session. Maybe that had something to do with it, but it shouldn't have. But it did.

Comment: @rinat.io Thanks! That was the problem for me!

Comment: @Satya Did you solve your Problem in the end? Would you consider adding it as an answer?

Comment: It wasn't solved. I stopped trying to run jasmine remotely like that.

Answer (score 1):

I was seeing the same error. I had an `expect` statement directly inside `describe`. I moved the `expect` inside an `it` block an the error went away.

Thanks to [rinat-io](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1224211/rinat-io) for the idea.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in different versions of angular in **angular-mocks.js** and **angular-scenario.js**
If your config looks like this:

```
files = [
    JASMINE,
    JASMINE_ADAPTER,
    '../app/lib/angular/angular.js',
//  ANGULAR_SCENARIO,
//  ANGULAR_SCENARIO_ADAPTER,
    '../app/lib/angular/angular-scenario.js',
    '../app/lib/angular/jstd-scenario-adapter.js',
    '../app/lib/angular/jstd-scenario-adapter-config.js',
    '../app/lib/angular/angular-mocks.js',
    '../app/lib/angular/angular-resource.js',
    '../app/lib/angular/angular-cookies.js',
    '../app/js/**/*.js',
    '**/*Spec.js'
];
```

try to avoid **ANGULAR_SCENARIO** and **ANGULAR_SCENARIO_ADAPTER** - replace it with ones that are embedded into your angular source ('../app/lib/angular/angular-scenario.js', '../app/lib/angular/jstd-scenario-adapter.js', '../app/lib/angular/jstd-scenario-adapter-config.js' in my case).

Comment: I don't think I'm using angular.

Comment: I use karma, jasmine for angular app tests. Followed your advice but still have same issue: jasmine.getEnv().currentSpec is null.

Answer (score 0):

What does your full test look like? I was also getting this error. My test looked like this:

```
'use strict';

describe("CalendarController", function() {
  var scope, $location, $controller, createController;
  var baseTime = new Date(2014, 9, 14);
  spyOn(Date.prototype, 'getMonth').andReturn(baseTime.getMonth());
  spyOn(Date.prototype, 'getDate').andReturn(baseTime.getDate());
  spyOn(Date.prototype, 'getFullYear').andReturn(baseTime.getFullYear());
  var expectedMonth = fixture.load("months.json")[0];

  beforeEach(module('calendar'));

  beforeEach(inject(function ($injector) {
    scope = $injector.get('$rootScope').$new();
    $controller = $injector.get('$controller');

    createController = function() {
      return $controller('CalendarController', {
        '$scope': scope
      });
    };
  }));

  it('should load the current month with days', function(){
    var controller = createController();
    expect(scope.month).toBe(expectedMonth);
  });
});
```

Notice that the SpyOn function is in the describe block. When looking at the jasmine code we find that SpyOn should be in a `beforeEach` or `it` block:

```
jasmine.Env.prototype.it = function(description, func) {
  var spec = new jasmine.Spec(this, this.currentSuite, description);
  this.currentSuite.add(spec);
  this.currentSpec = spec;

  if (func) {
    spec.runs(func);
  }

  return spec;
};
```

...

```
jasmine.Env.prototype.beforeEach = function(beforeEachFunction) {
  if (this.currentSuite) {
    this.currentSuite.beforeEach(beforeEachFunction);
  } else {
    this.currentRunner_.beforeEach(beforeEachFunction);
  }
};
```

These are the places where the `currentSpec` is set. Otherwise this will be null.
So in my example it should be:

```
'use strict';

describe("CalendarController", function() {
  var scope, $location, $controller, createController;
  var baseTime = new Date(2014, 9, 14);
  var expectedMonth = fixture.load("months.json")[0];

  beforeEach(module('calendar'));

  beforeEach(inject(function ($injector) {
    scope = $injector.get('$rootScope').$new();
    $controller = $injector.get('$controller');

    createController = function() {
      return $controller('CalendarController', {
        '$scope': scope
      });
    };
  }));

  it('should load the current month with days', function(){
    spyOn(Date.prototype, 'getMonth').andReturn(baseTime.getMonth());
    spyOn(Date.prototype, 'getDate').andReturn(baseTime.getDate());
    spyOn(Date.prototype, 'getFullYear').andReturn(baseTime.getFullYear());

    var controller = createController();
    expect(scope.month).toBe(expectedMonth);
  });
});
```

And then this will work because the spyOn is in the it block.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Didn't have any spies.

Comment: To help people fully answer this question should post the full example spec. There could be other functions which are trying to set the `this.currentSpec` which are failing. I was getting the same error and this was the solution, hopefully it helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this tweet, it has two fixes maybe one helps you out (they are related with the getEnv() method you are using:

https://twitter.com/dfkaye/statuses/423913741374074880

And the github links:

https://github.com/dfkaye/jasmine-intercept
https://github.com/dfkaye/jasmine-where

Maybe one of those will shed a light on your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was running into this issue and found the following article.
It seems as though the jasmine version and Angular versions were not working together.  When I made the changes the article outlines to angular-mocks.js the error went away.

http://railsware.com/blog/2014/09/09/make-angularjs-1-0-7-work-with-jasmine-2-0/

I ran into this while taking the PluralSight course: *Building a Site with Bootstrap, AngularJS, ASP.NET, EF and Azure.*  During the Unit testing module.